# Determine startpoint svg animation

Tags: css, animation, svg

I have exported an `svg` file from Illustrator.

Now I'm animating the line work. I know how to change the direction of animating but how (if) is it possible to determine the startpoint of the animation?

Here is an example:

```css
@keyframes lines { 0% {fill: none;}  50% {fill: none; stroke-dashoffset: 0;} 100% {fill: none ;stroke-dashoffset: 0;} }

.nose_outer{ animation: lines 4s ease forwards; stroke-dasharray: 186.514; stroke-dashoffset: -186.514; }
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 768 768">

   <title>svg</title>
 <g><!-- NOSE OUTER -->
  <path class="nose_outer" d="M396.667,406.31A17.016,17.016,0,0,0,381,416.686a17.008,17.008,0,1,0,0,13.266,17.011,17.011,0,1,0,15.667-23.642Z" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="5"/>
 </g>
  </svg>
```

By using negative and positive values on the `stroke-dashoffset` it's possible to change the direction.

Do I have to change something in Illustrator before exporting to `svg`?

Comment: *determine startpoint of the animation* - Maybe its just me but I couldn't understand this statement. What do you mean by that and what are you trying to achieve with it?

Comment: Didn't realize it was this unclear. My bad. The animation starts somewhere (startpoint) and stops somewhere. I would like to control where it starts

Comment: Oh ok, I got you now. That's because of how the shape is drawn. The imaginary pen is first moved to this point `M396.667,406.31` and then from here the arc is drawn. So, the animation starts from that position. Even if you reverse the direction the point itself wouldn't change. I think you'd need to change how the shape is drawn if you want the starting point to be different in this case.

Comment: That was what I was afraid of :-( I have to redo the entire illustration. Well to bad. Thnx anyway

Comment: I am not a SVG expert though and so don't know if there is any way around this without modifying the shape's `d` attribute itself. Give it sometime and see if you get any good answers.